# duck typing our rails models to display in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, model, duck-typing

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for this. It should be relatively straight-forward, but I'm not sure.

We have a few models that have some similar attributes, for example: `name`, `description`, `image`. However, for semantic reasons or otherwise, some of those attributes aren't 100% matching:

a `Video` model might have a `title` instead of a `name`, and an `Article` model might not have a `description` but rather have `content`.

We do however want to present those models in a view consistently in terms of layout. For example, we want to generate a list of items. Each item shows: a thumbnail on the left, name (or title) as a header, description (or truncated content) below. The thumbnail will link to the object page etc.

Now to the question:

**How can we 'duck type' those objects for the view with minimal `if` or `case` clauses?** Ideally we'll define some kind of an interface / module and apply it to each model so when we call `<something>.description` it knows how to fetch it for each object (either call `description` directly, or `content` etc)

Is there a standard / recommended way to do this in ruby / rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create aliases in each model for the generic name.  For example, if you want to always call the `description` method in your view, just add an alias for the attribute:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :description, :content
end
```

This will keep logic out of your views entirely and allow you to talk to your database object through a consistent interface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still wonder if there a way / if it makes sense to create some kind of a module that 'describes' this interface. i.e. defines all the methods that are being used and maybe allows individual models to include and overwrite them? Something similar to a Concern, but more view-specific...